# JMS message listener invoker cannot be cast to org.apache.qpid.client.AMQDestination

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, qpid

I am having one config file as below,

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class MyQpidConfig {
    @Bean("myQpidConn")
    public AMQConnectionFactory amqConnectionFactory() throws URLSyntaxException {
        AMQConnectionFactory amqConnectionFactory = new AMQConnectionFactory("URL");
        return amqConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean("myJmsContainer")
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer(@Qualifier("myQpidAdaptor") MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter ,@Qualifier("myQpidConn")AMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        messageListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
         messageListenerContainer.setDestinationName(destinationName);
        messageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(messageListenerAdapter);
        messageListenerContainer.setPubSubDomain(false);
        messageListenerContainer.setSessionTransacted(true);
        messageListenerContainer.setDurableSubscriptionName("MYSUBSCRIBER");
        messageListenerContainer.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
        messageListenerContainer.setAutoStartup(true);
        messageListenerContainer.setDestination((Queue) () -> "MYQUEUE");
        return messageListenerContainer;
    }

    @Bean("myQpidAdaptor")
    public MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter() {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(qpidMessageListner, "Consumer listener not set");
        MessageListenerAdapter messageListenerAdapter = new MessageListenerAdapter(new MyQpidMessageListner());
        messageListenerAdapter.setDefaultListenerMethod("onMessage");
        messageListenerAdapter.setDefaultResponseQueueName("MYQUEUE");
        return messageListenerAdapter;
    }
   
}
```

where destinationName is equal to

```
  ADDR:MYSUBSCRIBER:MYQUEUE; {"create":"receiver",
    "node":{"durable":true,"x-declare":
    {"exclusive":true,"auto-delete":false,
    "x-bindings":[{"exchange":"amq.topic","key":"MYQUEUE"}]}}}
```

and my Listener class is as below,

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class MyQpidMessageListner implements  MessageListener{
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message jmsBytesMessage) {
       log.info("Control Inside");
       //to do
    }
}
```

as a async consumer when i am running the my application at that time getting exception related to destination,

```
DefaultMessageListenerContainer - 
Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'com.my.MyQpidConfig$$Lambda$637/429515253@3aa1975' - trying to recover. Cause: com.my.MyQpidConfig$$Lambda$637/429515253 cannot be cast to org.apache.qpid.client.AMQDestination
```

If its related to AMQDestination  then how can i create the AMQDestination in java code.
I am not getting any resource for this QPID issue.
Any suggestion help must be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you're passing a lambda to [`org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.setDestination(Destination)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractMessageListenerContainer.html#setDestination-javax.jms.Destination-), i.e.:

```java
messageListenerContainer.setDestination((Queue) () -> "MYQUEUE");
```

This method needs a `javax.jms.Destination` implementation (e.g. `org.apache.qpid.client.AMQDestination`), not a lambda.

You're already setting the destination name, i.e.:

```java
messageListenerContainer.setDestinationName(destinationName);
```

So it's not clear why you're also trying to set the destination as well. These are two ways to configure the same thing.

I recommend you simply remove the code attempting to set the destination and leave the code setting the destination name.

Comment: In destinationName variable i am having this value ADDR:MYSUBSCRIBER:MYQUEUE; {"create":"receiver",
    "node":{"durable":true,"x-declare":
    {"exclusive":true,"auto-delete":false,
    "x-bindings":[{"exchange":"amq.topic","key":"MYQUEUE"}]}}} and when i am removing the line setDestination at that time getting the exception as Caused by: org.apache.qpid.QpidException: The name 'MYSUBSCRIBER:MYQUEUE' supplied in the address doesn't resolve to an exchange or a queue

Comment: Where did you get that syntax for the destination name?

Comment: Actually I have to configure durability,subscriber I'd ,auto-delete etc so I formed that string and passed it to destination name and it seems I am doing it in some wrong way.could you please correct me how can i set the attribute which are in destinationName

Comment: So you just made up that syntax or you got it from actual documentation?

Comment: no its not from doc i got from somewhere else,as per the doc i have made this topic://amq.topic//MYQUEUE?durable='true'&autodelete='false'&exclusive='false' and set it in setDestinationName() but getting exception as DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 
'topic://amq.topic//MYQUEUE?durable='true'&autodelete='false'&exclusive='false'' - 
trying to recover. Cause: unrecognized characters line:1,38:topic://amq.topic//MYQUEUE?durable='true'&autodelete='false'&exclusive='false'

Comment: Apache Qpid, but I am confused how can I do it in java if I am doing it in wrong way then please guide me how can I do it in right way

Comment: https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-java-6.1.5/jms-client-0-8/book/JMS-Client-0-8-Binding-URL.html#JMS-Client-0-8-Binding-URL-JMS-Topics

Comment: What versions of the Qpid broker and client are you using?

Comment: Could you please let me know where i am doing the wrong qpid-jms-client-0.50.0 and qpid-client 6.3.3

Comment: If I knew what the problem was, I would certainly tell you. However, I don't know what the root problem is. I've not used Apache Qpid before.